# What's the word for an "old lady"?

Tags: word-request

In anime, people sometimes use the words "aunt" or "auntie" to refer to a young female character. This is in fact a bit insulting, because in Japanese culture, calling a female a word that is considered to be old(er) is rude.

My question is, is there a similar culture in English-speaking country? What's the proper English words to use if one is going to convey such an insult? Can a native speaker understand it if I use "aunt"?

Comment: In anime this is "translationese", it is a literal translation of obasan. But such use is not common in English.  Are you looking for an insult that you could call a *young* woman (eg 25years old) that implies she is older, or a word you could call an *old* woman (eg 80) to imply that she is worthless?  How would you ever use this word?

Comment: Yes, this question isn't clear to me. I don't think it's common to insult young women by using a term meant to imply that they are much older. I can't say I've heard anyone use insulting terms like "old bag", "old biddy" etc to a young woman.

Comment: _Aunt_ conveys nothing about age in English. It used to be common for children to address family friends as Auntie and Uncle; the only other non-literal meaning suggests a woman who is kind to younger people.

Comment: @JamesK Yep, it's 'obasan'. I wonder whether an ordinary people (by ordinary, I mean he\she does not watch many anime and has not learned Japanese either) from US, UK or Canada etc. can get the insulting idea behind this word.

Comment: @KateBunting Would it be considered rude for a 15-year-old to call a 22-year-old female "aunt" if they are strangers to each other? Would the latter be unhappy about this?

Comment: It wouldn't be _rude_, but it would seem very odd to address a stranger as though they were a relation.

Comment: That has probably never happened.  A 15 year old would not call a 22 year old stranger "aunt". It would be completely non-idiomatic. It would be unusual for a 15 year old to speak to a 22 year old stranger *at all*. 99.9% would go into "polite mode", if they spoke at all.  And the 0.1% would be so exceptional that you don't need to worry about what messed up English they might produce.

Comment: I never watch _anime_ and I understand the suffix _-san_ to be a polite form of address, so I certainly wouldn't have guessed that it was meant to be insulting.

Comment: @KateBunting In Japan, the suffix -san can be used to show politeness, but the insulting point here is about age. 'Obasan' can indicate that the female referred to is not that young, and female in Japan don't want to be thought of as 'old' or 'not young'. Do girls and women have the same tendency in your country?

Comment: When I was a boy, my mother told me that it is impolite to suggest that you think that any female adult is older than 29. 'A lady's age is her own business', she said. She also said that if, when I grew up, a woman asked me to guess her age, it might be prudent to subtract seven years.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think that maybe staying young is a common dream for women all over the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding word in English is **grandma** or **granny**. You can also use **grandpa** or **gramps** for a man as an insult. While these words are obviously fine to use for your grandparents, [using them for other adults is almost always insulting](https://www.quora.com/Is-calling-an-old-woman-a-grandma-an-insult-in-the-United-States) (even older adults).

In more recent slang, you can also call someone a **boomer** (like in the expression [ok, boomer](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ok-boomer)). Note that this is insulting even when referring to someone who is a [Baby Boomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers).

Answer (score 2):

Not "aunt".  That word is used literally (to mean the the sister of a parent) or in an extended way (a close female friend of a parent, who may babysit etc).  Unlike (say) Japanese, English tends not to use family words like "grandmother", "aunt" or "sister" to mean "old woman", "middle-aged woman", "young woman".

There are ageist insults in English. Like much slang, these may be dialect, or local language.  "Old biddy" (faltering old woman) or "Old fogey" (old, unfashionable man). [Macmillian has a list](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/topics/informal-and-insulting-words-for-old-people) I've heard expressions like "Young fogey" (a young person who dresses or has social attitudes like an old man), but these are not common - Don't use them.

An interesting modern term is "a karen" (from the name, Karen) which is an insult for a white interfering, middle-aged woman with conservative attitudes. This is very modern slang, and it will probably be out of date soon, as teenagers move on to the next bit of slang.

Finally, I've heard "you're such a mum", used to mean "you don't do the cool things that other teenagers do".  But again, if you're not "one of the cool teenagers" you shouldn't use that expression.

Comment: When I was a teenager in London in the 1960s, if a rude kid, when e.g. rebuked for something such as boisterous behaviour, by someone visibly aged over about 50, who he did not know (it was usually boys), he might say contemptuously 'Sorry, Grandma!" or 'Sorry Grandpa!". This is one of a very restricted times when a younger person would address an older person with a family term.